# DBDatastoreStatus Usage with 3.0 Dropbox Sync API

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I recently upgraded to the 3.0 Datastore API on iOS, and I noticed that checking for remote changes is a bit different. I'm trying to figure out how to use `DBDatastoreStatus`'s new property `incoming` but I can't find any examples.

Is this how I would check if there are changes that will be available after the next sync?

```
__weak DBDatastore *weakStore = self.store;
DBDatastoreStatus *currentStatus;

[weakStore addObserver:weakController block:^(){
  //Like this?
  if(currentStatus.incoming){
    //Do stuff...
  }
}];
```

It seems like I need to associate the `DBDatastoreStatus` with the Datastore itself (`self.store`) somehow.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `if (weakStore.status.incoming) { ... }`. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/ios#listeners for an example.

Comment: Oh, okay, so it went from `weakStore.status & BBDatastoreStatus.incoming` to just `weakStore.status.incoming`. Makes sense and looks much better. :) Thanks!